How can I downgrade Ubuntu 24.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04?
Is there a way to downgrade ubuntu 24.04 LTS back to 20.04?

Does It is possible to change the version from Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, without formatting help?

Why do you want to do so? If you are facing certain problems, we can help you solve them

You provided no specifics as to what your install is, only mentioning releases - as product (Server? Desktop? etc) really matters. Desktops can non-destructively be re-installed for example with an earlier version; but you'll need to check what apps & data matters to you; as you'll be returning to older versions of software & they can have issues with datafiles from newer versions -- these checks are app specific & on you to do your homework as regards going backwards four years of version(s)....

This is impossible. In theory you would have to change the versions of all the packages, but this will be very difficult and will cause a huge number of problems. A reinstallation of the system will be necessary :(
